# Is my arp cache poisoned?

Tags: arp

I have these entries, starting with 224 on my computer and on the virtual machines, they cannot be deleted nor modified. Why is that happening. I am running Win 8.1

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.78 --- 0x4
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
192.168.1.1           9c-97-26-4e-58-a2     dynamic
192.168.1.255         ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

Interface: 169.254.133.85 --- 0xa
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
169.254.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

Interface: 169.254.56.140 --- 0xb
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
169.254.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static

Interface: 169.254.193.129 --- 0xc
Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
169.254.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static
224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static
224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static
224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static
239.255.255.250       01-00-5e-7f-ff-fa     static
```

Comment: Physical (MAC) addresses starting with 01-00-5e are standard multicast addresses. Nothing to worry about here, me thinks.

Comment: If they were the result of ARP poisoning, the entry would be "dynamic".

Answer (score 3):

#### I see ARP entries for the IP addresses `224.0.0.22`,  `224.0.0.251` and `224.0.0.252`

They are [Multicast addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address):

> A multicast address is a logical identifier for a group of hosts in a computer network, that are available to process datagrams or frames intended to be multicast for a designated network service.
>
> Multicast addressing can be used in the Link Layer (Layer 2 in the OSI model), such as Ethernet multicast, and at the Internet Layer (Layer 3 for OSI) for Internet Protocol Version 4 (IPv4) or Version 6 (IPv6) multicast.

Further information is provided below, but this kind of activity is normal.

---

#### What is `224.0.0.22`?

`224.0.0.22` is a [Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) version 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol) address.

This is normal traffic, and it stays on your local network.

> The Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) is a communications
>   protocol used by hosts and adjacent routers on IPv4 networks to
>   establish multicast group memberships. IGMP is an integral part of IP
>   multicast.
>
> IGMP can be used for one-to-many networking applications such as
>   online streaming video and gaming, and allows more efficient use of
>   resources when supporting these types of applications.
>
> IGMP is used on IPv4 networks.

Source [Internet Group Management Protocol (IGMP) version 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol)

---

#### What is `224.0.0.251`?

`224.0.0.251` is a [Multicast DNS (mDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) address.

> the multicast Domain Name System (mDNS) resolves host names to IP addresses within small networks that do not include a local name server.
>
> It is a zero-configuration service, using essentially the same programming interfaces, packet formats and operating semantics as the unicast Domain Name System (DNS).

Source [Multicast DNS (mDNS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS)

> I've seen those types of requests before - those certainly look much
>   like [Bonjour / mDNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29) requests to me. They use multicast IP address
>   224.0.0.251 and port 5353.
>
> The most likely source for this is [Apple iTunes](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1601), which as you
>   know comes pre-installed on Mac computers and is a popular install on
>   Windows machines.
>
> UPDATE: if this is a Linux box (not a Mac or Windows box), that's
>   probably the [Avahi daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29) then. Its [ZeroConf/Bonjour
>   compatible](http://wiki.debian.org/ZeroConf). Its installed by default, but if you don't use DNS-SD
>   or mDNS, it can be disabled.

Source [what is the multicast doing on 224.0.0.251?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483717/what-is-the-multicast-doing-on-224-0-0-251) answer by [suman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1203129/suman)

---

#### What is `224.0.0.252`?

`224.0.0.252` is a [Link-local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_Multicast_Name_Resolution)  address.

> The Link-Local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR) is a protocol based
>   on the Domain Name System (DNS) packet format that allows both IPv4
>   and IPv6 hosts to perform name resolution for hosts on the same local
>   link.
>
> It is included in Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008, Windows 7,
>   Windows 8 and Windows 10. It is also implemented by systemd-resolved
>   on Linux.
>
> LLMNR is defined in RFC 4795.

Source [Link-local Multicast Name Resolution (LLMNR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_Multicast_Name_Resolution)

---

#### Further Reading

- [what is the multicast doing on 224.0.0.251?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12483717/what-is-the-multicast-doing-on-224-0-0-251)